# How to fix ORA-12801 error in SQL Developer when display tables in connection browser

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

Using SQL Developer 18.4 MacOSX, I'm getting this error

> ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P000
>   ORA-01722:
>   invalid number

When I try to display the tables list in the connections tab.

I've isolated the Query. 
When I execute each part of the "union all" one by one, there is no error.
when I execute the all query you got the error.
When I disable the parallel option it works fine (`ALTER SESSION disable PARALLEL query`).

```
select * from (
  SELECT o.OBJECT_NAME, o.OBJECT_ID ,'' short_name, NULL partitioned,
                o.sharded,
                case when o.sharded <> 'Y' then o.duplicated else 'N' end duplicated,
                NULL iot_type, 
         o.OWNER OBJECT_OWNER, o.CREATED, o.LAST_DDL_TIME, O.GENERATED, O.TEMPORARY, NULL EXTERNAL
    FROM SYS.Dba_OBJECTS O 
    WHERE O.OWNER = :SCHEMA
    AND O.OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' 
union all
SELECT OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_ID , syn.SYNONYM_NAME short_NAME, NULL partitioned,
                o.sharded,
                case when o.sharded <> 'Y' then o.duplicated else 'N' end duplicated,
                NULL iot_type, 
       SYN.TABLE_OWNER OBJECT_OWNER, o.CREATED, o.LAST_DDL_TIME, O.GENERATED, O.TEMPORARY, NULL EXTERNAL
              FROM SYS.Dba_OBJECTS O, sys.user_synonyms syn
              WHERE  syn.table_owner = o.owner
              and    syn.TABLE_NAME = o.object_NAME
              and    o.object_type = 'TABLE'
              and    :INCLUDE_SYNS = 1
)
```

Comment: If you're getting this simply expanding the table list - which is what I think is happening - then you should probably raise this as an issue [on the SQL Developer forum](https://community.oracle.com/community/groundbreakers/database/developer-tools/sql_developer), if it hasn't already been brought up there; or as a service request through My Oracle Support.

Comment: @Didier - Any chance of pasting a link to any of the above (blog or SR) ?